# Exporting data from sqlite to a table in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

I have a programme which export all the database tables into multiple excel sheets :

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

filePath = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/mini programmes/Exportation des données/myExcelData.xlsx"

# database connection
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")

# writer for write the data into excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filePath, engine='xlsxwriter')

# create a data frame
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", conn)
for table_name in df['name']:
    sheet_name = table_name

    # sql query variable
    SQL = "select * from" + " " + sheet_name
    print(SQL)

    # load data from sqlite into dataframe
    dft = pd.read_sql(SQL, conn)

    # load data into excel file
    dft.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    print('Excel Sheet has been created successfully!')

writer.save()
```

What i need to know is how can i export data directly in a table instead of simple cells.
Thank's.